# Radio Button Labels not Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've got this component and im trying to map through API_DATA and return each country as a radio button but im getting only the radio icons and no label.

I'm new to React and im using MateriaUI which is working out so far, just having his issue

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import { propTypes } from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Image';


function MultiSelectFIlter(props) {


const [openCountry, setOpenCountry] = useState(false)



const [visibleFilter, setVisibleFilter] = useState(country)
 


const showFilters = () =>{
      
}


const API_DATA = [
    { brand: "BulkPowders", country: "UK", productType: "Shake" , category: 1 },
    { brand: "myProtien", country: "USA" , productType: "Bar", category: 2},
    { brand: "proteinWorks", country: "Aus", productType: "Gaming", category: 3 }
  ];

    return (
        <>
        <button onClick={() => setOpenCountry(true)}>^</button>
        {openCountry ? 
        <div>
        <FormControl component="fieldset">
                <FormLabel component="legend">Country</FormLabel>
                <RadioGroup aria-label="gender" name="gender1" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                {/* // visibleFilter is array , returning each as radioBtn, needs a unique function */}
                {API_DATA.map((e) => e[props.visibleFilter]).map((d) => <FormControlLabel value={d} control={<Radio />} label={d} />  )}
             

                </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
                <button onClick={() => setOpenCountry(false)} >OK</button>
        </div>
            :
            <> </>
        }
        </>
    )
}

export default MultiSelectFIlter
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you should move `API_DATA`  out of `showFilters ` and place it on its own . The `JSX` has no access to it the way your code is right now

Comment: sorry, that wasnt supposed to be in there, ive taken it out